# Add class to javascript datetimepicker generated by input with particular class/id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm not expert (at all) in Javascript, but I would like to add a the top arrow to a datepicker when it's shown from an "inline" input.

Normal date input:

```
<input class="date form-control form-icon-right form-calendar picker-open" type="text" name="date_ordered" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" placeholder="2016-09-22" />
```

"Inline" date input (I need to use id="inline-calendar" or preferably the class="inline-calendar" - if using the class I would get rid of the id):

```
<input id="inline-calendar" class="inline-calendar date form-control form-icon-right form-calendar picker-open" type="text" name="date_ordered" value="" data-date-format="MM-DD-YYYY" placeholder="Mar 17, 2018" style="font-weight: 600;"/>
```

I was thinking to add a class to the datepicker generated by the second input, I've tried to use the following script (that I got from here: http://jsfiddle.net/helen_mymedia/nvn6cu4q/), but it's not adding the class.

```
<script>
var inputIds = $('input.date').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get().join(' '); // space separated ready for removeClass

    $('input.date').datepicker({
       beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
           $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').removeClass(inputIds);
           $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').addClass(this.id);
       }
    });
</script>
```

How the datepickers should look like:
[normal date input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a88mD.png)
["inline" date input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glKvN.png)

Comment: `$('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').addClass(this.id);` 
this line is not working because `this.id` is undefined. you need to bind `this` to function.

Comment: Ah. How can I define this? It doesn't look it's defined in the script in the jsfiddle I've found, but it's working anyway.

Comment: I've also changed the line to be 
$('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').addClass('inline-calendar');
but it still doesn't work. (Also if the same change in the js fiddle works!).

Comment: Hey, `$('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').addClass('inline-calendar')` should work.  it is working here on my side. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/nvn6cu4q/16/. 
You need to have `inline-calender` in your CSS also to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately this is not what I want, as both inputs generate datepickers with the same attributes.
I want to have one input with the datepicker with no added class (let's say without background like in the jsfiddle) and the other input with the datepicker with the added class (let's say that the background is coloured like in the jsfiddle).
How can I achieve this?